# getting message " -bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long"

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to count the occurrences of a sub-string by grep command:

```
grep -il "touch screen" * | wc -l
```

The number of files is almost 20,000. I am getting the message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

Does it mean there are too many files? What is the remedy? I am using OS X.

Comment: Here is my command 'grep -il "touch screen" * | wc -l'

Comment: You have to partition the list of files, which is generally done with `xargs`. I'll post a complete answer in a few minutes if nobody has yet.

Comment: Oh but wait, much easier : use `grep -ilR  "touch screen" . | wc -l`. `-R` is recursive mode, you just pass it the directory and it will handle the files itself

Comment: yes, it's working, but if I want to see some line by  `-C` parameter, no line is showing.

Comment: You can't use both `-l` and `-C` if I'm not mistaken (since `-l` suppress the usual output)

Answer (score 3):

Technically, there aren't too many files, but the combined length of all their names is too large. When starting a new process, you pass its arguments to it in the form of an array of strings, and the operating system puts a hard limit on how large that array is allowed to be.

A simple, though inefficient, solution is to not use the expansion of `*` as the argument list to `grep`, but to use it in a shell *built-in* command:

```
for f in *; do
  grep 'touch screen' "$f"
done
```

Here, the shell is not trying to pass each string that `*` expands to in a single array, but using one element at a time. This requires a huge number of calls to `grep`, so a better solution is to use a tool that can batch up the results of the path name expansion into smaller, manageable sets.

```
find . -exec grep 'touch screen' {} +
```

Here, `find` passes as many files to `grep` as possible on each call, repeating the process until `grep` has been called on all the files.

Both of the previous techniques work because `grep` is *multiplicative* in the number-theoretical sense. That is,
    `{ grep '...' f; grep '...' g; }` and `grep '...' f g` produce the same output. If you can't split your command up into multiple invocations on smaller subsets, the only solution is to hope the command can read arguments from a file (either a named file or via standard input) instead.

Comment: Heh, I was bothering with `xargs` and `find` never came to mind, go figure ! By the way, would you happen to know why the "Argument list too long" looks like it's thrown by `grep` while it's a problem generic to the shell?

Comment: Technically, `execl` (or whichever `exec*` function is being used) raises an `E2BIG` error when the array given it is too large. That function is called from a process that is forked from `bash`, but before it actually becomes `grep`. The error is reporting that `bash`, while attempting to start `grep`, received this error from `execl`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to `grep` all the files of a directory, I would recommend using `grep`'s `-R`ecursive mode :

```
grep -ilR "touch screen" . | wc -l
```

should be equivalent to your

```
grep -il "touch screen" * | wc -l
```

The two commands will be different if your directory contains subdirectories (but then you would have had errors with your current `grep` command).

---

Another option would have been to invoke `grep` on each file in a loop, then `wc -l` the output of the loop :

```
for file in *; do
    grep -il "touch screen" $file
done | wc -l
```

---

I commented about `xargs`, which would indeed be great to pass the output of a command as parameters of another :

```
ls . | xargs -L 20 grep "touch screen" | wc -l
```

Here it limits the number of arguments passed to `grep` to 20, and will call `grep` as many times as needed.

However, I don't think it can work on the expansion of `*` and rather needs to work on the output of `ls` as I showed. Parsing the output of `ls` is error prone, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to expand `ls *`? it's really more a matter of putting `xargs` in the right place along with it's options (I'm not sure exactly why you have xargs where you've placed it); and yes I agree with your comment about parsing `ls`, but sometimes it's a fine solution.

Comment: `for file in .; do` is wrong; it needs to be `for file in *; do` to iterate over the files in the current directory, rather than just the single string `.`.

Comment: @l'L'l it's perfectly able to act on the output of whichever `ls` you want (but I don't think you want `ls *`), however I don't think it can reuse bash's expansion you see in `grep "pattern" *` without using another executable such as `ls`. Oh, and I've placed the `xargs` to partition the output of `ls` when passing it to `grep`

Comment: @I'L'I : What's the difference between the shell expanding `grep targ *` and `ls *`. I don't think in this case there would be any difference, it will  still be an arg list that exceeds MAX_ARG (or what ever that is called). But I'm not interested enough to generate a test case w 20,000 files ;-) . Good luck to all!

Comment: I did however just test `ls *` VS `ls` in a directory that I have with long filenames and 2400 files. `ls` (without the `.`), worked fine, but `ls *` got `[Arg list too long]`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I doubt anyone wants to use `ls *` anyway : the `*` gets expanded by bash first, then `ls` does its job with all these files. In the best case it's the exact same thing as `ls .` or `ls`, in a worse case it will display subdirectories' content (with a crappy format if I remember well), and in the worst case you pass over the number of arguments limit.

Comment: @Aaron : yep, you have filled out the list of reasons, I was focusing on the O.P.s issue with `-bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long` . Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter: absolutely... and it used to be common to see `ls *` in use (I think everyone has been guilty of it at some point). I think the way around the arg list being too long is to parse it using `-I{}`, or `-n`... and yes, there are obviously better ways to be had :)